# How to migrate tx_cal_category records to sys_category records?

Tags: typo3

I would like to migrate tx_cal_category records of the TYPO3 cal extension to sys_category records including all relations and plugin category selections. Has perhaps someone an idea or even a script and would be so kind to publish it here or to send it to me?

I just saw that Tim Lochmüller has an import script in his calendarize extension which could perhaps be useful but it will surely still needed a lot of work to adapt it for this purpose. As I would have to migrate about 3000 events I cann't adapt the records manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/4.2.1/class.ext_update.php#L338 as inspiration where I migrated relations including flexforms from my own category record to sys_category.

Answer (score 0):

In the installtool is an update-wizard especially for that purpose, so it's included in newer cal-versions.